# Weibo API - get fan count without authentication

Tags: php, api, weibo

My client has a website and he needs to show fans count of his Weibo Fan page. How can I get the fan count without authentication to Weibo API. As I see almost all requests needs authorize. But what I need is when user visits site we will show the site owner/company fan count like that.

Comment: Would you show us what code you have so far, and tag this with the language you are using, so people can help you on the bit you are stuck with? If you have not tried anything, please do so first.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: I am using php for website and I need to know the Weibo API endpoint which I can call to get fan count without authorization. Without this api end point I cannot start coding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for Weibo, the followers or fans count is only available to the page/account Admins. General public cannot view the fans count, hence, it is something that wouldn't be available without authentication.